# How to avoid Null reference exception when datagrid rows are not visible within grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

```
<DataGrid x:Name="gridView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="263" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="235" AutoGeneratingColumn="gridView_AutoGeneratingColumn" GotFocus="gridView_GotFocus">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

//Get count and data of checked parts from gridview
            foreach (var row in gridView.ItemsSource)
            {
                bool IsChecked = (bool)((CheckBox)gridView.Columns[0].GetCellContent(row)).IsChecked;

                if (IsChecked)
                {
                    var part = ((TextBlock)gridView.Columns[1].GetCellContent(row)).Text;
                    var code = ((TextBlock)gridView.Columns[2].GetCellContent(row)).Text;
                    var um = ((TextBlock)gridView.Columns[3].GetCellContent(row)).Text;
                    addToPartList(part, code, um);
                    checkCount += 1;
                }
            }
```

The purpose of this code is to collect row data from all the rows the user has checked. The datasource of the Datagrid is a list with a checkbox column added to the grid. The problem is that if the grid is large enough that the grid scrollbar is needed, the rows outside of the visible grid return a null reference exception when being converted into type bool. How can I get around this problem?

Comment: Why don't you use a null check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                if (((CheckBox)gridView.Columns[0].GetCellContent(row)).IsChecked != null)
                {

                    bool IsChecked = (bool)((CheckBox)gridView.Columns[0].GetCellContent(row)).IsChecked;

                    if (IsChecked)
                    {
                        var part = ((TextBlock)gridView.Columns[1].GetCellContent(row)).Text;
                        var code = ((TextBlock)gridView.Columns[2].GetCellContent(row)).Text;
                        var um = ((TextBlock)gridView.Columns[3].GetCellContent(row)).Text;
                        addToPartList(part, code, um);
                        checkCount += 1;
                    }
                }
```

As @Sievajet suggested, I added a check for nulls before the conversion and resolved the issue. This no longer throws a null reference exception.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but just a litle imrovement.
you can avoid two if's by this;

```
if ((CheckBox)gridView.Columns[0].GetCellContent(row)).IsChecked??false)
{
    var part = ((TextBlock)gridView.Columns[1].GetCellContent(row)).Text;
    var code = ((TextBlock)gridView.Columns[2].GetCellContent(row)).Text;
    var um = ((TextBlock)gridView.Columns[3].GetCellContent(row)).Text;
    addToPartList(part, code, um);
    checkCount += 1;
}
```

unless you want IsChecked variable elsewhere.